# Visual Studio Extensibility - ProjectInfo.Document is always null

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

When using the Visual Studio extensibility SDK I have an instance of a [`ProjectItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  I'm trying to get the text from this item so I can do some replacements on it.  The way that I've seen this done is by using the properties on [`DTE2.ActiveDocument.Selection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.document.selection.aspx).  However, the [`DTE2.ActiveDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tkyf2yb.aspx) isn't the document that I need so I can't use that.  When I try to access the `ProjectItem.Document` object which contains a [`Selection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.document.selection.aspx) property the document is always null and I get a null reference exception.  I've also tried the following which doesn't work (i.e. the `Document` is valid, but the `Selection` property is null):

```
Document document = null;
if (!projectItem.IsOpen)
    document = projectItem.Open().Document;
```

I tried the following but it didn't give me the correct document since the ProjectItem I'm dealing with isn't the active document.  Is there any way to implement something similar to the following code that uses `ProjectItem.Document` instead?

```
TextSelection selection = DTE2.ActiveDocument.Selection;
selection.SelectAll();
string text = selection.Text;
selection.Delete();
//Do replacements
selection.Insert(text);
```

To summarize, **how do I get a TextSelection instance from a ProjectItem instance?**

Comment: Where is the code that uses `Selection` exactly?  Post the a link to the documentation.  Post the information on the `Selection` property.

Comment: @Ramhound Updated the question with the information you asked for.

Comment: When you debug your code, after `selection` is set equal to `ActiveDocument.Selection` is it `null` or equal to `TextSelection` object?  If this its equal to `null` then you have located your problem.  Where is the code where you select which document is being used?  Its not clear what type `_vsApp` is exactly.  The example code provided for `Selection` is not supported within VS2012.

Comment: @Ramhound The problem is that the ActiveDocument is not the document I want to adjust.  I already have a ProjectItem and I want to get the text from that.

Comment: If thats the case why exactly are you using `ActiveDocument` instead of `ProjectItem`?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm *not* using ActiveDocument.  I only included that in my question to let people know that it will not work for my purposes.

Comment: This is why we encourage people to post what they actually tried.  As you noticed every single comment I made, was under the impression, this was the actualy code you were using.

Comment: @Ramhound I had tried using DTE2.ActiveDocument, but it didn't contain the document I wanted which is why I included it so people wouldn't suggest that as a solution.  I guess I thought it was fairly clear, but I've obviously failed to communicate my problem effectively.  I believe the question is now phrased in a way that should not be confusing.

Comment: @Ramhound In addition, the last sentence has always been there and I think it fairly well summarizes my ultimate question (how do I get a TextSelection instance from a ProjectItem instance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual when dealing with the VS SDK, the answer is a bit obscure.  The way that I solved it (right or wrong) is to make the [ProjectItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance the active document and then use the [`DTE2.ActiveDocument.Selection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.document.selection.aspx) property to get the text.  This is accomplished via the following:

```
if (!projectItem.IsOpen)
    projectItem.Open(@"{7651A701-06E5-11D1-8EBD-00A0C90F26EA}").Document.Activate(); //EnvDTE.Constants.vsViewKindCode

TextSelection selection = _vsApp.ActiveDocument.Selection;
selection.SelectAll();
string text = selection.Text;
selection.Delete();
//Do replacements
text = ReplaceTemplateValues(text, replacements);
selection.Insert(text);
```

Is there a better way?